# Objective C: Getting 'Invalid Initializer Error' when setting CLLocationCoordinate2D location

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocation

I am trying to find and set the location as shown below but I keep getting the error 'Invalid Initializer'

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location =[self.mapView addressLocation];
```

Where addressLocation method is as show below

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                       [searchBar.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSError* error;
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double latitude = 0.0;
    double longitude = 0.0;

    if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else {
        //Show error
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;

    return location;
}
```

Can you advise why I am getting the 'Invalid initializer' error? I have already imported the corelocation location framework and also imported the header files. So not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking `[self.mapView addressLocation]`. Shouldn't it be `[self addressLocation]`? I'm presuming `mapView` is the `MKMapView` in your class and doesn't have any `addressLocation` method.

Comment: I tried to use [self addressLocation] but am still getting the same error 'invalid initializer'...

Comment: This is a silly question but do you get any warnings on the assignment line when you build your project? Are you assigning in the same class where addressLocation function is defined?

Comment: @Gary, I didn't get a warning, it gave me an error on the assignment line 'Invalid Initializer'. Also the addressLocation function is located in the same class where I am trying to assign the location.

Comment: Is addressLocation function declared in the .h file?

Comment: @Gary, yes you hit the jackpot. I was careless enough to not include it in the header file. Added it in and it's working now. Thanks!